# How can I block flash from obtaining a list of available fonts in my browser?

Tags: privacy, flash, fingerprinting

How can I block Flash, at least in Chrome, from obtaining the [list of available fonts in my browser](http://browserspy.dk/fonts-flash.php)? It seems that the combination of fonts available is the easiest way to [fingerprint a browser](https://panopticlick.eff.org).

Answer (score 2):

**Use the open source Flash/SWF player - LightSpark.**

---

If LightSpark currently provides only a Mozilla browser plugin, encourage the developers to port to Chrome, or port it yourself.

If LightSpark doesn't currently have a toggle for disabling or anonymizing font information, upload a patch to the project, or encourage the project developers to do so.

Comment: This may seem a high-effort solution, but if we encourage this project - we could eventually end-up with full user empowerment over Flash execution in browsers. A security plus in my book.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a solution for the future, besides, Flash will probably be completely dead before we end up "with full user empowerment over Flash execution in browsers".